# Extension methods for generics

Tags: swift

In `kotlin` we can extend functionality of generic type, `apply` function for example:

```
inline fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T
```

Thereby we can use this function to accurately set properties of objects like this:

```
titleView.apply {
    setTextSize(10)
    setTextColor(RED)
}
```

Or even save common styles as constants:

`T.() -> Unit` means extension function for type `T` which returns Unit (`void`, nothing)

```
val TITLE_STYLE: TextView.() -> Unit = {
    setTextSize(10)
    setTextColor(RED)
}
//...
titleView.apply(TITLE_STYLE)
```

Is something similar possible in swift? My best try looks like:

```
func apply<T: UIView>(_ param: T, _ style: (T) -> ()) {
    style(param)
}
```

We can use this as following:

```
let titleLabel: UILabel = ...
apply(titleLabel) { label in
    label.font = UIFont(name: "SFUIText-Regular", size: 14)
    label.textColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Or using constants:

```
let accentTitle: (UILabel) -> () = { label in
    label.font = UIFont(name: "SFUIText-Regular", size: 12)
    label.textColor = UIColor.red
}
//...
apply(titleLabel, accentTitle)
```

Is it possible to write `apply` as extension function in swift? This is ugly and can fail at runtime:

```
extension NSObject {

    func apply<T>(_ style: (T) -> ()) {
        guard let obj = self as? T else {
            preconditionFailure("Object \(self) does not confirms to type: \(T.self)")
        }
        style(obj)
    }
}

titleLabel.apply() { (label: UILabel) in
    label.font = UIFont(name: "SFUIText-Regular", size: 14)
    label.textColor = UIColor.red
}

titleLabel.apply(accentTitle)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Kotlin: What happens if the block is not applicable to the object (e.g. because it has no "setTextSize" method)?

Comment: @Martin R, compile-time error, because then function won't confirm to expected type. I'll add this detail to question.